# Why is AC impedance 1.3 times the DC resistance?

Tags: resistors, ac, resistance, impedance, transmission-line

I have seen [several times](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-resistance-depend-on-the-frequency) that AC impedance is considered to be 1.3 or 1.5 times the DC resistance. But, never found the reason behind this consideration. Is it an experimental or observational consideration?

Comment: Post a link to where you have seen it because, at the moment, this question makes no sense.

Comment: I wanted to focus on AC impedance of a part of transmission line.@BrianDrummond

Comment: If you mean skin effect then say it.

Comment: Yes, I meant skin effect.

Comment: Please provide a link then to where you have seen this.

Comment: my link:-https://www.quora.com/Does-the-resistance-depend-on-the-frequency

Comment: If that is a rule of thumb, it is for an incredibly specific set of circumstances. It's not to be used as a general rule and it should have been explained in much further detail. Skin effect of the transmission line is frequency dependent, material (of the conductor) dependent, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a graph of the AC resistance of litz wire as frequency rises to 2GHz: -

[image]

At no particular point is there some special ratio of "1.3 to 1.5" that stands out - if you keep increasing frequency, the current in a solid wire occupies a progressively smaller part of the overal cross sectional area of the cable and this means the cable devlops a higher resistance.

Whereas on the OP's link this was said: -

[image]

On the face of it the guy making the statement is incorrect. Here's someone else saying the same thing: -

[image]

It's basically wrong!! See this: -

[image]

The above formula was taken from [this](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-3/more-on-the-skin-effect/) site in case you need to know what the wire gauge factor is.

Clearly, as frequency rises there is no limit to how high the AC resistance increases.

Comment: I do not understand your diagram, what's the Y-Axis? I'd think it should be AC resistance divided by DC resistance? But why is the value not 1 in the beginning then?

Comment: @Arsenal yes it's not 100% clear - the Y axis is absolute resistance of an arbitrary length wire so therefore down at LF the resistance is largely what the DC resistance is - maybe I can find a better picture.

Comment: That would be nice, as it currently is with those tiny values I can't really tell where the point of 1.3 * DC resistance is frequency wise. (not that it really matters, as the statement is just horrible, but for clarity)

Comment: @Arsenal got one!

Comment: That's better. Fun fact though that you now have a factor of 1.3 for 255x0.05 mm litz at 1 MHz. This must be a very common point of operation for some folks to say it's always like that...

Comment: @Arsenal I've seen a few audio cables that have ~1.3 at 20kHz too. If you look hard enough at anything you'll go insane!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to keep in your mind whatever your application:
Impedance is a more general term for resistance that also includes reactance. 
Reactance is a measure of the type of opposition to AC electricity due to capacitance or inductance. This opposition varies with frequency.